# Why one of my table upload way longer than the other one?

Tags: sql, azure

I have 2 table want to upload to the Azure SQL DB, There are the info below

| name | rows | reserved | data | index_size | unused | Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table A | 21523 | 13840 KB | 12968 KB | 800 KB | 72 KB | 25 |
| Table B | 50324 | 24528 KB | 22616 KB | 1824 KB | 88KB | 31 |

Table A took half a minute to upload and table B took 7 and half minutes to upload. use the same upload method.

There is the code using Python and Pandas to upload data

```
def upload_data(self, data, table:pd.DataFrame):
   logging.info("Connection to sql database established, attempting to upload data...")
   data.to_sql(table, self.engine, if_exists="replace")
   logging.info("upload data successed")
```

I do understand data Complexity could be also a factor but why there are such a big different between these two tables upload time?

Thanks All

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned different parameters as : rows, data, index size, columns. So as you can see that Table 2 is having more data than Table B.

Code you are entering through python/ panda would be as there are more index in table B so would require more time to dedicate to table A

Other than that you can check network latency issues also if above issues you are finding is not valid.